# Proving that $\sum_{n=0}^r (-1)^n \binom{r}{n} (s+r-n-1)!/(s-n)! = 0$ without Taylor expansion

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Let $0<r\leq s$ be two integers. 
I would like to prove that the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^r(-1)^n \binom{r}{n} \frac{(s+r-n-1)!}{(s-n)!}$$ is equal to zero. One possible way to prove this is to use the identity $\log(xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)$, then use the Taylor expansion of $\log(x)$. The above sum will appear as the coefficient of $x^ry^s$ of $\log(xy) - \log(x) - \log(y)$. I would like to have a direct proof, without using the Taylor expansion.

Comment: It's an $r$-th difference of a polynomial of degree $r-1$.

Comment: what do you mean by $r$-difference?

Comment: And what polynomial of degree $r-1$?

Comment: ok got it. Many thanks :)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Make that an answer, please. :)

Answer (score 1):

$(s+r-1-n)!/(s-n)!=(s+r-1-n)\cdots(s+1-n)$ is the number of 1-to-1 functions from $[r-1]$ to $[s+r-1]$ which miss a fixed set of $n$ points in the image.

So, by inclusion-exclusion, your formula counts the 1-to-1 functions from $[r-1]$ to $[s+r-1]$ whose image contains the whole $[r]$.

Answer (score 0):

> We obtain for integral $0<r\leq s$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^r}&\color{blue}{(-1)^n \binom{r}{n} \frac{(s+r-n-1)!}{(s-n)!}}\\
> &=(r-1)!\sum_{n=0}^r(-1)^n\binom{r}{n}\binom{s+r-n-1}{s-n}\\
> &=(r-1)!(-1)^s\sum_{n=0}^r\binom{r}{n}\binom{-r}{s-n}\tag{1}\\
> &=(r-1)!(-1)^s\binom{0}{s}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (2) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.